# Setting Pydev to use with Openstack

Tags: openstack

I am currently looking into OpenStack and want to know about the development environment that I could use for debugging different issues that arise when I run it on my VM. By development environment I am referring to the IDE that can help me understand the functioning and call flow of OpenStack. I have Pydev installed with Eclipse on my machine but I don't know how to run all the Openstack dameons (nova-api,nova-compute,nova-network, glance-api etc.) together in Pydev.

Any help would be much appreciated.

(P.S: I am trying to avoid pdb for now, as Pydev would allow me to see the code and my location in it more conveniently...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with OpenStack, but if you could use pdb, you could definitely use the PyDev remote debugger the same way: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

Comment: Thanks! This seems promising ... but I have another problem related to debugging greenlet coroutines when I use something as strong as pdb. When a coroutine starts waiting for an event and such an event occurs, I lose control over the program. Do you have any suggestions for it ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this question got asked on the OpenStack dev mailing list too on the thread [[OpenStack] Development/Debugging](http://openstack.markmail.org/thread/ofrr6xpei7gprzs3) where there are some answers.